# How to use scriptlet based id in jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have to use dynamic ids in my form, based on jsp variables in a scriptlet. How can I select the correct element using jQuery's id selector without getting errors?

Here's my code:

```
<form name="intakeOnly" id="intakeOnly_<%=complaint%>" method="post" action="../Intake.do">
<table class="normal">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Clinician Signature: </b> <span id="cSigI_<%=complaint%>"><%=clinicianSig%>,<%=signedDate%></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="submitSig_<%=complaint%>" name="submitSig" value="Sign and Save" onClick="intakeSubmit();"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function intakeSubmit() {
   var complaint = <%=complaint%>;
   var fname = new String("<%=userFirstName%>");
   var lname = new String("<%=userLastName%>");
   var date = new String("<%=DateUtils.getDate()%>");
   jQuery("#cSigI_"+complaint).append("<br>"+fname+" "+lname + ","+ date); 
}
```

Comment: Don't use new String("") in javascript for creating a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
var complaint = <%=complaint%>;
```

should be

```
var complaint = "<%=complaint%>";
```

The lines following that should be changed to match that syntax, `new String(str)` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

there is `escape(string)` and `unescape(string)` functions to deal with such characters